# Circular motion of two bodies: how to determine when they meet up again?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, angular-velocity

[image]

Let's say that there are two satellites, one of them moves in the red orbit and the other one in black one. At the time t0 they start together on the green point. How can I set equations to deduce when are they going to meet each other again? Mass is not important.

Comment: A way you could use is that given a  parameterisation e.gX(t),y(t).for them to collide the 2 x components of position must be equal, rearrange to find the time at which this happens, do the same for the y and  compare the times,  the one that matches both is the correct time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use Keplers third law $T^2/a^3=\textrm{const},$ you will know the relative orbital periods by knowing the relative size of the major axes of the two orbits.  You can calculate $nT_1=mT_2.$ If there are not whole numbers $n$ and $m$ that make the equation true, they will never meet exactly again.

Comment: (though they will still meet *within one satellite diameter* in some finite time).